# Remote debugging via SSH tunnel: receiving "There was a problem sending x bytes on socket y: Broken pipe"

Tags: ssh, phpstorm, ssh-tunnel

The idea is to setup "Remote debugging via a SSH tunnel". In more detail: we run PhpStorm on my Windows PC locally. Run Xdebug on a remote Centos server. We connect via Putty using the SSH tunnel option.

We are following the below guide:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html

The problem is that if we start CLI debug using `XDEBUG_CONFIG=idekey=phpstorm php myscriptcommand.php` on the remote server we receive the error like below in the ssh screen
`xxxx.xx: There was a problem sending 318 bytes on socket 4: Broken pipe`

Netstat shows us

```
prompt on server$ netstat -a -n | grep 9000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      1 remote_server_ip:47160     66.249.79.197:9000      SYN_SENT
```

**Question**: How can we prevent the broken pipe from occurring or what is going wrong here?

Comment: Not an SSH expert so could be completely wrong here .. but try using different port (e.g. 9001) for all Xdebug communications in case it conflicts with php-fpm that you may have installed there (as it uses 9000 by default).

Comment: This was it and I'll pass it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem was solved by changing the default port to a free port, in this case 9001. php fpm was running on port 9000.

Both the port for xdebug (the putty/ssh tunnel and in phpstorm need to be updated to port:9001 (or another free port)

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem, and found that xdebug had started the default remote debugging.

And my Phpstorm was also on, xdebug's DBGP protocol was blocked in the process of data reception

> xdebug.remote_autostart=1

I document the process to my Blog: https://tkstorm.com/posts-list/programming/php/xdebug-timeout-question/